# What effect will i get if i update fcm library from 9.0 to 15.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

The app i am working on is using `play-services:9.0.1` libraries, I am planning to updates these to `15.0.0`, After updating i am not seeing any error in any of the class file.

```
 compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1')
 compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0')
```

My question is are there any side effects that can occur, or i need to test after upgrading `play-service` libraries from `9.0.1` to `15.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update firebase to 15.0.0, you need to also update google play services to 15.0.0, to prevent any mismatch.

Also you need to check the release notes here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I have updated all of the other play-services libraries that i used to 15.0.0, I have checked the release notes, i am concerned that from code point of view there is no change, I am not sure if anything breaks logically at production.

Comment: Maybe try and test, but there does not seem anything that is deprecated. All I see is fixes, and new features. Can check by clicking ctrl+F and searching "messaging"